# 403 Forbidden when trying to access API via DRF

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to access a django server using django-rest-framework from angular using the following service:

```
myapp.factory("GetData", ["$resource",function($resource) {
   return $resource(
      "http://local/path/**/users/:username/",
      {},
      {
        "query": {
        method: "GET",
        isArray: true,
        headers:{
          "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
      }
    },
    {
     stripTrailingSlashes:false
    }
   );
}]);
```

When I put the URL in the browser, I get the desired output, but the problem is that when I try to access via Angular, in my console I am getting a 403 forbidden  error. Can anyone explain to me whats causing this. and how I can possibly fix this issue.

My url.py looks as follows:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import UserViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(prefix='users', viewset=UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

My views.py file is as follows:

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from rest_framework import viewsets
 from .models import users
 from .serializers import UserSerializer

 class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = users.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Comment: Besides the HTTP status code, what is the body of the response? What does it contain?

Comment: This is the whole error I am getting in my console:             GET http://local/path/**/users/ 403 (Forbidden)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:12011
sendReq @ angular.js:11776
serverRequest @ angular.js:11571
processQueue @ angular.js:16383
(anonymous) @ angular.js:16399
$eval @ angular.js:17682
$digest @ angular.js:17495
$apply @ angular.js:17790
done @ angular.js:11831
completeRequest @ angular.js:12033
requestLoaded @ angular.js:11966

Comment: What happens if you open that URL: local/path/**/users in your browser (i.e. not through angular)?

Comment: It works well. It gives me the contents as anticipated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by combining what @Bipul Jain suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044910/7210105 (above) and also altering this link in my $resource

> "http://local/path/**/users/:username/"

I removed **http://local/path** from the link and the 403 forbidden error went away.

Comment: aah. This was another one. Not sure if just my answer can be accepted here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 403 forbidden is coming to browser block cross origin requests. 
You need to enable allow CORS at your API server by setting appropriate headers.

You can lookup https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

For this you need to add in your installed apps.

```
'corsheaders'
```

And just set to test it out. Check for fine tuned settings in the docs.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

**Edit**

Also you need to add this in your middlewares.

```
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
```

Comment: This method did not work. But I believe its something to do with CORS indeed. Is there another way of dealing with CORS besides the one u identified here.

Comment: Forgot to add the middleware config. Is the request reaching the server ? if yes then what's the error message from there ?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/accounts/users/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403. I get this error before I whitelist localhost:3000 @Bipul Jain

Comment: I edited my answer. Did you add the middleware and tried ?

Comment: After whitelisting localhost:3000 I only get GET http://localhost:8000/accounts/users/ 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: You whitelisted localhost:3000 and hitting port 8000 .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134869/discussion-between-tatenda-and-bipul-jain).